# Parasite which can live by itself

Tags: creature-design

Is there a reason for a human sized parasite to infect other animals if it can very well hunt alone and defend itself?

I thought about it injecting eggs into other animals, but that's pretty much killing it and using it as food, not really parasitical.

By parasite I intend something that is not entirely predatorial, like a vampire would probably only care to suck dry a prey and kill it, but it's not like it's gonna get attached to an animal for long periods like a leech would or a lamprey. But then again, a giant leech or lamprey would still kill any land and most water animals in one bite.

Comment: A fictional example of a parasite that is a human sized but can otherwise hunt and defend itself is the vampire.

Comment: What does human-sized parasite mean? When you say parasite I think of something like a tubeworm or botfly larvae that lives inside another creature's body. Hard to manage for something human sized. . . .

Comment: @Daron a vampire... the real world equivalent would be a tick. Yes, it's not *human sized* (that would be terrifying) but it's an external parasite.

Comment: Among animals, [facultative parasitism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facultative_parasite) is relatively uncommon; it's much more common among microbes, plants and fungi. On the other hand, [kleptoparasitic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleptoparasitism) animals are quite common, with hyenas being an example.

Comment: @VLAZ i was thinking something spider shaped but not really spider but quite spider but not really

Comment: @user81643 But do you mean something that lives permanently attached to or inside the host's body?

Comment: @VLAZ That question was directed to the OP. I am asking whether something like a vampire counts as a parasite under the author's definition. I wouldn't usually consider a vampire bat to be a parasite myself.

Comment: @Daron not, but livint permanently attached to anpther animal is a possibility and prefred, but being detached doesn't kill them

Comment: @Daron Vampire bat IS a parasite (and classified as such) from a purely biological standpoint. In fact it is the only true parasite among mammals. This, along with abundance of temporary parasites such as mosquitos would require further clarification from the OP - is temporary parasitism an acceptable answer? Also I would be careful with fantasy examples such as vampires, as they are depicted in various ways in various works, and could be either a parasite or a predator depending on whether it kills the victim upon feeding.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are humans who are parasites...

Comment: Human sized parasites? Are we talking lawyers or politicians here? ;-)

Comment: By this definition, isn't a human who keeps a cow or goat for its milk, but doesn't kill and eat the cow or goat, a "human-sized parasite"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Wasps do this - make a giant wasp**

Some species of wasps both eat other creatures and inject eggs into them.

> Wasps tend to be omnivorous. They prefer a diet that constitutes of
> nectar, honeydew, and a vast range of invertebrates such as ants,
> cicadas, butterflies such as blue morpho butterflies, spiders,
> caterpillars, and flies.
> https://www.bioexplorer.net/what-do-wasps-eat.html/

> Terrifying giant parasitic wasps that lay eggs INSIDE baby insects
> using ‘sex sting’ discovered in Africa
> https://www.thesun.co.uk/tech/10099018/parasitic-wasp-egg-sex-sting/

Answer (score 3):

Injecting eggs into other animals and Killing them for food is totally different.

When these parasites lay their egg inside another animal, say a cow, then the egg gets a relatively safer environment to develop and constant warmth to mature.

When the baby comes out of the egg, it gets instant fresh food and safety from the outside world, it can keep feeding on the host and by the time it eats enough of the host that the host dies, the baby is mature enough to survive further.

You won't get features like these with dead animals.

Comment: @user81643 I agree with this. You need to look up life cycles of organisms. Your parasite is unlikely to be a parasite in its adult stage, and maybe you don't even view this as being a parasite, but it is. Lots of insects do something similar, like the jeweled wasp. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emerald_cockroach_wasp

Comment: @DWKraus and a reasonably well known fictional example where an organism has a parasitic part of its lifecycle is the xenomorph from *Alien*. They'd lay eggs which hatch into the "facehuggers", which in turn deposit an embryo in a living organism. That embryo hatches and eventually consumes the victim, then grows to what can be called *close* to human size (usually larger but depiction have varied). That last adult stage doesn't exhibit parasitic behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a colony of unicellular organisms (essentially a multicellular organism, but less, well, solid) it's perfectly feasible.

The largest fungus on record lies underground and spans *3.5 miles,* sprouting clumps of yellow-brown mushrooms above the surface to reproduce. Considering that's the largest fungal *colony* in the world, our colony should be perfectly capable of achieving human size.

As for why it would infect other organisms when it can hunt and fend for itself, the answer is simple:

1. It *can't* obtain food by ingesting other organisms, it simply doesn't have the ability to. In other words, since it can't eat other creatures for food, it's an obligate parasite and needs to leech nutrients from a host. Likely ways are bloodsucking since the blood contains and distributes the nutrients gained from digestion or by taking advantage of the host's digestive process (like tapeworms do, perhaps?). So this creature must have a host to live.
2. Since it can't obtain nutrients on its own, it's not hunting for food, but rather for a *host,* which it will use its amorphous body to engulf and metamorphosize. Yes, you read that right. Either it'll break down and reassemble the host like a caterpillar in a cocoon, using retroviruses to incorporate its genes into the host so they *technically* become one entity, or it'll invade the host's cells (so it can access the nutrients supplied to and energy produced inside the cells) and alter its genome to suit its purposes.

This parasite could be an interesting take on the whole zombie concept, a freaky alien monster, or the explanation behind the Imposters in Among Us.

Answer (score 2):

**Parasitic larvae.**

You have not said what "parasitic" means. I presume you want a creature that lives permanently attached to or inside the host's body.

There are no human-sized creatures like that in the real world simply because no host is big enough.
The next best thing is a parasite with several stages. The fully grown form is the size of a human. It hunts and kills things. It's only when it reproduces does the  parasitism start.

After mating the large creature injects its eggs into the skin of another large host. The young hatch inside the creature and, over the next few weeks, eat their way deeper inside. They then form a cocoon and metamorphose into their second stage. The second stage is still only about an inch long. It hunts and kills insects and over the next few years grows into the adult form.

For extra size, the infection is set up so only one larvae survives after eating most of the edible material on the host, and all of its brothers and sisters. The coocoon  gestates inside the desiccated body of the host.  Hormones are released to make the host hide somewhere safe before dying, and to block decomposition odours that might attract other scavengers.

Let's say with all that extra work the final creature that emerges is the size of a crab maybe?

Comment: [The largest tapeworms](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetragonoporus) can grow to be 40m (130ft) and have a surface area of about 2 square meters (about as much as an adult human). They infect whales.

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw Any idea how heavy those guys are? I'd imagine FAR less than a person.

Comment: I cannot find any estimates of any cestode weight. But if we assume that the largest one is 40m long, 5cm wide and 2cm high, and as dense as water, it could reach 60kg. It would probably be much less than that, maybe 40kg, because the worm is not that wide throughout its length. For comparison the "standard weight" of a male adult human is 72 kg, I think.

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw 62kg, close... Usually untrained and not obese people weight between 350 to 385 grams per centimeter in height. But it can get down to 300 or less grams for really tall children.

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw If you assume the worm has square cross section (maximise mass relative to surface area) I'm getting a 2$m^2$ surface area worm should be only 5/4 cm each side and a mass of only 5kg.

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw Which is still much bigger than the parasites I had in mind when I wrote the answer. But not immediate relevance to the question since the tapeworm cannot survive as a predator outside the host.

Comment: @daron You got a point and I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

**Sustainability.**

Suppose I am a bandit lord.  I can show up in a village, kill them all and take what they have.  Ho ho!

But when I come back to the village there are only weeds and empty houses because I killed everyone last time.  Wah.

If I can go find new villages that would work.  But what if they are scarce?  Worse, once I leave my territory what if there are other bandit lords out there who take umbrage with me showing up?  Those other bandit lords are a lot tougher than villagers who go around in their underwear.

I could kill all the villagers.  But better is to show up and leave them alive and just take some of their stuff.  Then let them go to work and get new stuff for the next time I show up.  I can use my local village sustainably.  Instead of predating on them, I am parasitizing them - drinking their blood little by little instead of eating their meat.

I might actually occasionally be useful for them.  If some small time bandit lord shows up thinking he will kill them all and take what they have, ho ho!, I can instead make an example of that bandit lord and have him dance in a cage while the villagers poke him with sticks.  Parasitism could grade into a [protection racket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_racket).

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in kleptoparasites:

> A bird, insect, or other animal which habitually robs animals of other species of food.

https://centerofthewest.org/2019/03/25/kleptoparasites-pirates-world-birds/

The parasitic bird is perfectly capable of hunting but bullying and stealing is easier.

Answer (score 0):

[Facultative parasites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facultative_parasite) are an actual thing known in nature. Indeed there almost have to be in order for parasites to evolve, there has to be a transitional state between being a free-living animal and one that is dependent on living inside a host species.

Some animals are free-living but have a larval stage that lives within another organism and eventually kills them (i.e., ichneumon wasps or the xenomorphs in *Alien*). This is technically not a **parasite**, it is a **parasitoid**. That said the boundary between the two is often blurry, insects have been known to be parasitized by ichneumon wasps and survive even after the wasp larvae pupate.

Vampires were mentioned by a poster but that wouldn't necessarily be considered a *parasite*, in most cases they'd be considered a *predator* that merely happens to drink blood. To paraphrase E.O. Wilson, "a parasite is a predator that eats prey in units of less than one". Of course, the vampire definition is highly subjective. On the one hand, if the vampire can kill humans but more often feeds non-lethally, that is more parasitism. Additionally, one could argue the vampire living among humans and using human society for shelter counts as a form of parasitism. All this serves to highlight is the line between parasite and predator is very blurry.

The problem you are going to face is you need a really, really big host organism in order to sustain a human-sized parasite. Like whale or sauropod-sized. The benefits of parasitism is that the host carries you around or gathers energy on its own, and then you swoop in and profit from it. The benefits you get are directly proportional to the difference in size between yourself and your host. If the two animals are about the same size, it makes more sense to consume it completely to recoup the energy costs of capturing it rather than just parasitizing it. By contrast a smaller parasite (e.g., a vampire bat) couldn't take enough blood to kill its prey even if it wanted to.

You mention lampreys, but the thing with lampreys is lamprey attacks often are lethal because the sea lamprey is so large and stays attached for so long the victim dies of blood loss and organ damage. If sea lampreys "only" reduced fitness but weren't lethal they wouldn't be a horribly destructive invasive species in the Great Lakes, where they have almost wiped out the whitefish, lake trout, and burbot. [Perhaps unsurprisingly, larger fish are more likely to survive sea lamprey attacks, because the sea lamprey doesn't suck them dry.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0380133003704961)

There are a lot of difficulties in being a very large parasite:

- From an energetic perspective, there is no benefit in letting your prey live. You are giving up free calories...for what? There is the argument that if you restrain yourself now you have prey for later, but animals aren't like that. Indeed, even to most human societies throughout history the idea of resource conservation was utterly alien, we only started realizing the importance of resource conservation when our societies started planning on the scale of years and decades rather than focusing on year-to-year survival.
- If you are much larger than your prey, there isn't much of a point to hold back because it's more energy efficient just to eat them and get all the nutrition. Otherwise you have to chase them down again and drain them again.
- You have to waste additional energy restraining prey that is close to your own size. You can't really sneak up on the prey as easily as a smaller parasite like a vampire bat, tick, mosquito, or leech could.

At this point it stops becoming parasitism and starts being predation with extra steps.

Probably the closest thing to what you want is a [micropredator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitism#Micropredator) like an IRL saber-toothed blenny, some piranhas, or a cookiecutter shark. Lampreys, mosquitos, and vampire bats are technically considered micropredators as well. Saber-toothed blennies and some piranhas bite chunks out of larger fishes' fins and skin. Cookiecutter sharks are infamous for biting plugs of flesh out of large marine animals like big sharks, tuna, and whales. However, even in these cases the animals are still dramatically outsized by their hosts.